# Is there any way to see from which table/view a software is loading/using data from its database?

Tags: sql-server

I basically would like to know from which table or view, a software is loading data from when opening, e.g.: when I push save button, which table does the software uses to update data or load when an action is triggered.

I've tried some ways, like seeing the transaction log file, or the active connections in the database. Also I expected a query like:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM active_transations_due_to_software
```

I'm using SQL Server Express License.

Comment: Look at the query plan (ctrl-L).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) and use the [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=SQL%20Server%20Profiler%20is%20used%20for%20activities%20such,...%205%20Correlating%20performance%20counters%20to%20diagnose%20problems.).